# Pattern Match build multiple Seqs

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm looking at a way of building up multiple Seqs using a pattern match like this:

```
statuses.map(result => {
    (status.matchStatus, status.source) match {
      case ("Matched", Some(API.name)) => //Add status to a matchedApi seq
      case ("Matched", Some(MANUAL.name)) => //Add status to a matchedManual seq
      case ("Changed", Some(API.name)) => //Add status to a changedApi seq
      case ("Changed", Some(ENTRY.name)) => //Add status to a changedManual seq          
    }
})
```

Does anyone know if this is theoretically possible or am I going completely the wrong way of building these lists up?

Comment: You can do it with a `.foldLeft` or with a (tailrec) function

Answer (score 2):

If it's acceptable to have dynamic groups you can group you values by status + source tuple

```
val groups = statuses.groupBy(x => (x.matchStatus, x.source))
```

and after access it like this

```
val matchedApi = groups.get("Matched", Some(API.name)).getOrElse(Seq.empty)
val changedManual = groups.get("Changed",Some(MANUAL.name)).getOrElse(Seq.empty)
```

Comment: Is it possible to say, get me all of the groups which have "Matched" as the first key?

Comment: groups.filter(entry => entry._1._1 == "Matched")